# Show in NSTableView, HTML table tag contents

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, nstableview

I'm working in a project and I need to represent table contents of a webpage in a `NSTableView`. I tried with an `NSXMLParser` but it only works fine with XML code, cause it's more specific with the nametags but in HTML there's a lot of "td" objects and "a" objects. I read that `Webkit` can help with that, but I'm a beginner with Cocoa an MacOS programming, and I'm a bit lost with that.

---

If anybody cares or needs also an "HTML Parser" or some way to interpet HTML with Cocoa, I found some external libraries. [That one](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) works nice for me.

Comment: Uh... why isn't the edit an answer?